# Dynamic query string php

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a job board on our Wordpress website and each job has an Apply Now but which redirects to a form. Rather than build a new form for each job, I am trying to pass the Job Title (which is the page title) to the form but cannot get it to work.

So the button is located on this page for example:
http://mywebsite.com/careers/engineering-job

Page title is **Engineering Job**

The code for the button I'm trying is this..

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://mywebsite.com/careers/apply/?job_name=". $_GET["$title"] ."'">APPLY NOW</button>
```

Any idea how I can get the title into the query string so it would pass to my form as

```
http://mywebsite.com/careers/apply/?job_name=Engineering Job
```

Comment: You most likely need to <?php echo urlencode($_GET[$title]); ?> to account for special characters.

Comment: You'll need to properly build a string in PHP; you can't just drop `$_GET` into your HTML like that....

Comment: What technique are you using? Is this javascript or php?

Comment: would  the dynamic engineering-job page would have a title variable you can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WordPress' `wp_title()` function and then `urlencode()` to properly encode all special characters.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://mywebsite.com/careers/apply/?job_name=<?php echo urlencode(wp_title(' ', FALSE)); ?>'">APPLY NOW</button>
```